# PHP+nginx+Yaf use one page to get another page stucked and nginx crashed

Tags: php, nginx, yaf

I want to use curl to get one page content and save as static html file,
environment: Yaf+PHP5.3+nginx;

When I run the code, page was stucked loading, after several seconds nginx crashed.

test1 Controller code below:

```
class Test1Controller extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $ch = curl_init('http://www.alitui.com:8010/test2');
        curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($content);exit;
    }
}
```

and test2 controller code below:

```
class Test2Controller extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 1;exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: This URL http://www.alitui.com:8010 is unreachable unless it locked by IP or something

Comment: O,it a local test domain ,I wrote it in my hosts file.